# Showing UILabel's text

Tags: ios, swift

Following the *iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, 6th Edition* 's guide, I try to make a Quiz project using in swift.

The ViewController code here

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var answerLabel: UILabel!

    let questions: [String] = [
        "What is 7+7?",
        "What is the capital of Vermont?",
        "What is cognac made from?"
    ]
    let answers: [String] = [
        "14",
        "Montpelier",
        "Grapes"
    ]
    var currentQuestionIndex: Int = 0

    @IBAction func showNextQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentQuestionIndex += 1
        if currentQuestionIndex == questions.count {
            currentQuestionIndex = 0
        }

        let question: String = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
        questionLabel.text = question
        answerLabel.text = "???"
    }

    @IBAction func showAnswer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let answer: String = answers[currentQuestionIndex]
        answerLabel.text = answer
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }
}
```

But running with non visual text except the int one.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question does not make sense at all

Comment: Seems like the content of the label is more than its width. Please assign the sufficient width label to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't constraint the width of `questionLabel` and `answerLabel` to specific number. Try to give the constraints properly like label width is equal to viewController's width like in the screen shot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code with demo project and it's working fine. And your problem is with `UI components` you have added in `storyboard`.

Assign constraint to your `questionLabel` like shown in below image:

[image]

Basically I have assigned `Leading`, `Trailing` `Top` and `Height` Constraint to label and set `Alignment` to `center`.

And same thing with other label and buttons. And it will look fine.

For more info check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=10015117932399557755) demo project with your code.